# What are possible side effects of having fields on User object which should be frequently updated?

Tags: apex, dml, user-record, locking

For integration purposes I would like to store a few custom fields on User object which should be updated 10-30 times per day.
Is it considered a good practice to have such fields on User object?
Are there any side effects of updating User records with such frequency e.g. locking errors etc.?

Comment: Some more detail about what type of information these fields contain would be useful. Usually, `Hierarchy Custom Settings` are a good fit to store configurations for specific users, but it is hard to say given the level of information provided.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It  should have Large Text (10000) with average size about 2KB, Datetime, and another Large Text(10000) with average size 600KB. Custom Settings will not work here because of the size of the fields. Also there is a risk of hitting limit on 10MB for total Custom Settings size because of large number of users. We are considering either storing this info on User or on a new Custom Object.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly consider putting these fields on a separate object. For one thing, any field you update on the `User` object shows up in the `Setup Audit Trail`, so making several such updates per user per day on a large user base would bloat that tracking to the point it would be borderline useless.

It will also be much less complicated to unit test any functionality layered on top of such an object, as it will not be setup data.

There are likely other risks associated which I have not touched on, but it is hard to see a compelling argument that adding these fields to `User` would be worth the costs already outlined.

Comment: I just checked on Dev Org. I have modified text field on User record. The change didn't appear in Setup Audit Trail. Also User record modifications are not mentioned in Monitor Setup Changes with Setup Audit Trail
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5